# Inject Service In Extendable Class Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, nebular, ngx-admin

I am aware of [DI injection pattern](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action) in angular but now I am implementing [Nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/introduction#auth-module) so the class needs to be extend , hence unable to use constructor in this case  (given that have never worked with super calls)

[image]

The issue is

```
this.authenticationService
```

is null despite of adding in provider.

Please help me solve this or let me know how to inject service in this case without a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Update your constructor to:

```
export class NgxLoginCustomComponent extends NbLoginComponent {
    constructor(
        nbAuthservice: NbAuthService,
        @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) options = {},
        cd: ChangeDetectionRef,
        router: Router,
        authService: AuthenticationService
    ) {
        super(nbAuthservice, options, cd, router, authService);
    }
}
```

Refer [this issue](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1234) in Nebular's [repository](https://github.com/akveo/nebular).

Comment: thanks @dipen but have read it there also its a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

you have to inject all the params in child constructor again call super() with params as follows.

```
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {

   constructor(prentDepService1:any,prentDepService2:any)
   {
     super(prentDepService1,prentDepService2);
   }
}
```